# Can i reset my whole operating system i mean can factory reset the data on my OS ??

Tags: system-installation, updates, system, files, filesystem

my hard drive is suddenly filled up and that's 80GB ?! and all i have is few doc files and few snaps installed thats's it ? i tried to install a snap earlier this day and that was not successful so i think that did something with the memory. I just need some help please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I *really* don't advise doing this if it's *just* for the purpose of saving storage, but you can create a live USB of your distro of choice and then overwrite the partition that had your original install. This will not affect your new OS, but your old one will be completely removed.

***IMPORTANT NOTICE: FORMAT THE DRIVE BEFORE YOU INSTALL! THIS CAN AND WILL CAUSE PROBLEMS!***

For some reason, some Linux installers do not (by default) format the partition that you will install Linux on. PLEASE make sure that you format the partition BEFORE beginning the install process. If you are dual-booting, select the 'Something else' option to manually figure out how the partition scheme should be done/divided/whatever

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an application called Disk Usage Analyzer available from the AppCenter to determine where the culprit is. With that information you can determine what needs to be removed and figure out the best course of action. The best solution will depend on whether the files are system files or user files in your home directory. The aforementioned application will allow you to drill down to the specific file(s). If you are unsure add a screenshot to your post for further assistance.